# Upgrading PostGIS and PostgreSQL but running upgrade to PostgreSQL it errors?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, installation, postgis-2.0

I want to upgrade

> PostGIS（2.0.4 ---> 2.2.3）

and

> PostgreSQL (9.2.4  ----> 9.6)

so

```
First I upgrade PostGIS 

1、install PostGIS 2.2.3 on postgresql 9.2.4 
2、alter EXTENSION postgis   2.0.4 ---> 2.2.3

Second I upgrade PostgreSQL by using pg_upgrade

1、Install PostgreSQL 9.6 and PostGIS 2.2.3
2、Running pg_upgrade
```

But it's error:

```
could not load library "$libdir/postgis-2.0"
error:could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.0" have not file or dir
```

so I guess it seem in the older PostgreSQL (9.2.4) have some function must using PostGIS 2.0.4

> but in PostgreSQL 9.6 I haven't installed PostGIS 2.0.4

So

If I want to upgrade what should I do?

Comment: What does `pg_config --pkglibdir` print?

Comment: `/opt/postgres96/lib`      `/opt/pgsql9.2/lib`

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;`